# Server - connect to existing PPTP vpn and serve web traffic over vpn

Tags: server, vpn, pptp

I need to extend access to my database backed application to remote members of my team.  This application is hosted on an Ubuntu server.  Some of the data we're storing is protected by a contract which doesn't allow any devices storing this data to be publicly accessible via the internet.

I've had this server serving on my local network for a while via the .local domain, but I would like to add it to my PPTP VPN as a connected asset.  So far I haven't been able to find anything that shows how to connect an UbuntuServer to a VPN.  Maybe my Google-fu is poor, but every search turns up directions for setting up a VPN server on Ubuntu server

Does anyone know of any good resources that explain how to connect Ubuntu server to an existing VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install pptp-linux along with other PPTP module ,

Add your provider at /etc/PPP/peers/VPNPR

Connect to VPN using "pon VPNPR"